# django - filtering objects across multiple templates?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter objects across two templates. One (the parent) should display the five most recently updated, and the other should display all of them.

I have the latter working perfectly with the following code:

**views.py:**

```
...
class ChannelProjectList(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'projects_by_channel'
    template_name = 'channels/projects_by_channel.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
       self.channel = get_object_or_404(Channel, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
       return Project.objects.filter(channel=self.channel)
...
```

**HTML:**

```
{% for project in projects_by_channel %}
 {{project.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I go to "include" it on the parent page it breaks.  After some research I understand why that is happening and why that isnt the proper way to do it. I dug around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107377/django-template-filter-queryset), which seems to be exactly what I'm trying to do but when I implemented it, not only did it not work it but also broke the page that is working.

This feels like a pretty simple thing, but since this is my first project I'm running into new things every day and this is one of them.

*Final Solution:*

With the help of [this](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html) I realised I needed to copy in the same get_queryset into the second template view, which I was then able to call into the template using "view.channel_projects"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities. First you could define two context variables (like its done in your linked solution) or you could [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) the `qs` in the template.

**1. Option slice:**

This one would display all:

```
{% for project in projects_by_channel %}
 {{project.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

This on only displays 5 entries:

```
{% for project in projects_by_channel|slice:":5" %}
 {{project.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

**2. Option define two query sets:**
(views.py)

```
def get_queryset(self):
   self.channel  = get_object_or_404(Channel, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
   self.channel2 = get_object_or_404(Channel, id=12)#whatever
   context["list"]  = Project.objects.filter(channel=self.channel)
   context["list2"] = Project.objects.filter(channel=self.channel2)[0:5] #this slices the query set for the first entries. If you want to order them first(by date or whatever) use "order_by()"
   return context
```

(html)

```
{% for project in list %}
 {{project.name}}
{% endfor %}


{% for project in list2 %}
 {{project.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to display a single qs but one time the whole thing and in another template just the first 5 you are better suited with using the `slice` argument in the template. It keeps the view clean and simple and you don't have to query two times. 
I hope that helps if not leave a comment.

Comment: Slicing seems a lot cleaner. The problem seems to be that when I'm on the channel template, it isnt finding any "projects in projects_by_channel" and is just displaying the {% empty %} part. It feels like the template_name part of the generic.ListView is only allowing it to work on that template, if that makes sense?

Comment: for different views you have to define different view functions. So on another template you have to write a view and in these views you have to define the context variables for each template. The second template must have a view somewhere. If you use "include" the same variables will apply.